# Design: Background thread with a Spring service

Tags: spring, service

I have Spring service which after performing some tasks,initiates a background Async tasks. The task itself I have defined as a component.
Now, If I have to use some method belonging to my the service which initiated the thread. I can Autowire the service in the thread(Component) and it will work. Problem is...The design. It brings in kind of circular dependency? 
How can we tackle such issue?

ServiceA-> Starts a ThreadA component->ThreadA Needs to call a method in the ServiceA.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an @Async annotated method as described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

A non tested example:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String mySyncMethod(){
       return "Hello World";
    }

    @Async
    public Future<String> myAsyncMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        return new AsyncResult<>(mySyncMethod());
    }

}
```